# Is it possible to write a C program that functions differently according to argv[0]?

Tags: c, argv

Is it possible to write a C program that functions differently according to `argv[0]`?

In fact, I am working on an exercise from a C textbook. The exercise is to write a program that converts uppercase to lower or lowercase to upper, depending on the name it is invoked with, as found in `argv[0]`.

[Edit] FYI, the exercise is from K&R's textbook

[image]

Comment: If I have understood correctly then what you need is to write a program that converts uppercase to lowercase letters in the program name stored in argv[0] and vice versa.

Comment: @n.m. he is probably facing the problem of resolving a questionable exercise.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: No. The assignment is to write a program that converts input (or arguments) from lowercase to uppercase if `argv[0]` contains, say `LowerToUpper` and that converts from uppercase to lowercase if `argv[0]` contains, say, `UpperToLower`.

Comment: Actually, there are some linux tools that exactly behave like that (several symlinks go all to the same application, which performs different tasks according to name it was started with).

Comment: @Aconcagua: I was thinking about that. `vi` and `view` are the same executable, but the latter starts in read-only mode. A more interesting question is which standard or common tool has the most different behavior depending on its name?

Comment: Do you count `busybox` as a standard tool, @EricPostpischil?  It has dozens of distinct behaviors depending on the name it's invoked with.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: It is not on my macOS system, which is clearly the gold standard for standard and common tools, at least within a radius of 50 meters, so no. :-)

Comment: From [Busybox README](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/README?h=1_31_stable): *The behavior of busybox is determined by the name it's called under: as "cp" it behaves like cp, as "sed" it behaves like sed, and so on.  Called as "busybox" it takes the second argument as the name of the applet to run (I.E. "./busybox ls -l /proc").*

Comment: @EricPostpischil Have some trouble to accept an OS as gold standard when considering the rather poor [market shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems) (when compared to competitors).

Comment: @Aconcagua: Popularity is not gold.

Comment: @Aconcagua, it's probably equally as common to use a single binary with multiple directory entries ("hard links") to it, as to use symbolic links (which some old filesystems didn't support, back in the days when K&R was written).

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to make a program behave differently depending on the value of a variable? In that case, the answer is yes.

Comment: but what is the problem of comparing `argv[0]` with some constant text and have different execution depending on the result (standard `if` in almost any *normal* language).

Comment: @Aconcagua: I checked, and it may not be easy to distinguish , but those areas exceed the 50-meter radius I specified. By more than 10%!

Comment: There are plenty of Unix tools that work this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a C program that functions differently according to argv[0]?

Yes, it is possible, very simply. For example:

```
if (0 == strcmp(argv[0], "say_hello")) {
    printf("hello\n");
} else if (0 == strcmp(argv[0], "say_bye")) {
    printf("bye\n");
}
```

Comment: `argv[0]` holds the program name. Probably it includes the path, so `strcmp` won't work.

Comment: This was just an example and the need of the original poster does not elaborate on the path part.

Comment: No he does not. But that is implicit in his question. But you could use `strstr`.

Comment: @user803422 It is not a one program. There are two programs with names stored in argv[0[

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Not necessarily - on linux, with symlinks, you can have different names for one and the same programme...

Comment: @Aconcagua: And even on systems without symbolic links, you could get the same behavior by copying the file to a file with a different name.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hm... Cornercase, depending on definition of programme... There are, albeit identical, two separate executables. We could e. g. update just one of them (changing only one behaviour, although programme/executable actually changed both). I personally prefer looking at them as two programmes...

Comment: @aconcagua. Symlinks aren't the only possibility. Hard links work too. Since the executable is likely read-only, you could consider a hard-link a kind of lazy copy :-)

Comment: @rici The matter with *'all'* and *'none'* statements (or *'always'* and *'never'*) is that one single counter-example suffices to invalidate them...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could simply choose what function to use based on the program name

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
    if (strcmp(av[0], "upper") == 0)
        do something;
    else if (strcmp(av[0] "lower") == 0)
        do something;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Uh, oh... `if(ac == 1) toupper(av[1])`, undefined behaviour in sight... Apart from, toupper/tolower accept single characters, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes is definitely possible. In order to correctly manage `char` values in this exercise I'd suggest to use `ASCII` tables, which you can view [here](http://www.asciitable.com)

Idea is: 
We know Uppercase letters start from decimal value 65 and end in value 90. 
Lowercase letters start from 97 and end in value 122.

Now, if we have, for example, letter `D` which decimal value is 68, in order to make it become lowercase we just have to add 32, which becomes 68 + 32 = 100, which is exactly value of lowercase letter `'d'`.

Similar thing if we have Lowercase letter `j`, which value is 106. We subtract 32 obtaining 74, and that's the exact value of Uppercase letter `'J`.

Those two functions use previous method in order to convert respectively lowercase letters to uppercase and viceversa.

```
void toLower(char *string){
    //For any letter in *string
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
      //If letter at index I is really uppercase
      if(string[i] >= 65 && string[i] <= 90)
        //it becomes lowercase by adding 32 to its ASCII value
        string[i] += 32;
    }
}

void toUpper(char *string){
  //For any letter in *string
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    //If letter at index I is really Lowercase
    if(string[i] >= 97 && string[i] <= 122)
      //it becomes Uppercase by adding 32 to its ASCII value
      string[i] -= 32;
}
```

Now the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  //Taking program name from argv[0]
  char *upperOrLower = argv[0];
  //Adding 2 to Program Name in order to remove characters '.' and '/' from String
  upperOrLower += 2;
  //Retrieving String given as argument
  char *string = argv[1];
  //If Program Name is lower
    if(strcmp(upperOrLower, "lower") == 0){
      //We have Uppercase string, so we use toLower function
      printf("String before calling toLower: %s\n", argv[1]);
      toLower(string);
      printf("String after calling toLower: %s\n", string);
    }
    //Else if we have upper as program name
    else if(strcmp(upperOrLower, "upper") == 0){
      //We have Lowercase string, so we use toUpper function
      printf("String before calling toUpper: %s\n", string);
      toUpper(string);
      printf("String after calling toUpper: %s\n", string);
    }
}
```

Now by compiling above program as:

```
gcc program.c -o upper
```

and executing it by typing:

```
./upper hello
```

Output should be:

```
String before calling toUpper: hello
String after calling toUpper: HELLO
```

The other way around, if we compile it by typing:

```
gcc program.c -o lower
```

and then we execute it by typing: `./lower HELLO` 
We should get output:

```
String before calling toLower: HELLO
String after calling toLower: hello
```

You may want to add a check on `argc` value, which tells us how many arguments you provided to program or you might get errors if there aren't enough.

This should be all of what your exercise is asking for.

Hope I've been clear.